# How does Android LVL behave when unpublishing an App from the Play Store?

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am a little bit helpless with the Android LVL.
A few years ago I have published an Android App in the Play Store. The App is not free for use so users have to purchase it. To verify a user really has bought the App I am using the LVL. The app will only work if the LVL respond with *LICENSED*. So far so good.

With the beginning of 2017 I want to unpublish the App from the App Store. By unpublishing the App the installed version on the users' devices will not be deleted. And for sure users who have bought the App should still be able to use the App life long (complying with the *Google Developer Distribution Agreement*).

What will LVL answer when I unpublish the App from the Play Store? Will the App still get a *LICENSED* response? Unfortunately the Google Docs do not mention this scenario...Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I have published a whole new App in the Play Store for 0,59€. Then I have bought this App with a whole new Google Account (no developer or test account) and installed it. LVL check ended in LICENSED, so far so good.
I have then unpublished the App, waitet until the App was removed for new users and checked again with the LVL. I still got LICESNED as callback. So unpublishing an App does not affect the way the LVL answers to users who have bought the App before it was unpublished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When app is unpublished following happens

- App is not available for download
- Cannot be found in play store
- Can be uninstalled by user, yet cannot be reinstalled.
- User cannot download any information on app even if provided with direct url
- App is not removed from your developer console

So in short unpublishing app does not mean the app is deleted forever.
In fact it's quite far from it, u can update app info, even publish it once again.

As LVL goes, user should receive normal responses. U are simply hiding app not removing it :)

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Is this more a "theory" saying "it should be working" or have you ever tested it? The App has more than 40k active users so I must get sure everything will work as expected.

Comment: Yes i did not had a chance to test it myself. That is why "it should". 
Think about it this way before publishing, we can create your beta all functions are working even without app being published.